# UI button is enabled

Tags: c#, lua

how to check any UI button is enabled and visible in Lua.
Suppose you get a control any UI button. Now we want to check if the button is `Visible`,
`Enabled` or `MovedToObject`

Suppose you have a button creation code in C#
and you are writing a Lua script as you have automation id and main application window title

Now I am able to get control on a button. I can click on that button through Lua script and get parent of that button control by below code.
I need to know how can I check from Lua script is it visible or enabled

Comment: Lua does not directly have access to any "UI button". What library are you using from Lua that allows you to touch UI elements?

Comment: Put another way: this isn't a question about Lua (it's Lua not LUA, being the Portuguese word for Moon). It's a question about whatever UI system you're using (is this an addon for a game perhaps?)

Comment: Suppose you have a button creation code in C# . and you are writing a LUA script as you have atuomation id and main application window

Now I am able to get control on a button. I can click on that button through LUA script and get parent of that button control by below code. I need to know how can I check from LUA script is it visible or enabled

Comment: Have modified and put more details in question. Please veiw it again

Comment: Added C# tag.  You should include the code giving you problems.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to connect your Lua (_stop calling it "LUA"_) scripts to C#?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using LuaInterface to connect Lua and CLR, you could make your button object globally available in Lua:

```
luaInstance["ButtonName"] = buttonInstance;
```

Then in Lua script:

```
isEnabled = ButtonName.IsEnabled
isVisible = ButtonName.IsVisible
```

(Not tested; I just started playing with LuaInterface.)

Answer (score 0):

if imagename.isvisible==true then

--print image is visible

else

--print image is not visible

end